# How to make django inlines orderable by clicking the title?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a project which I need to add "sort" ability in inlines by clicking the title

For example, I want to alphabetically rearrange the data in "Choice" by clicking the title "Choice". Same functionality with other inline fields as well. Is there any way to achieve it?

http://media.wilsonminer.com/images/django/related-objects-mock.gif

Answer (score 0):

The Inline model you have defined in admin.py has a ordering field for that:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Choice
   ordering = ("name",)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the rearranging of fields by clicking the title, not pre-fixing it by ordering it.

Comment: Like things I can do in this page   http://www.everythingability.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/django_admin.jpg

Comment: I see, then you are looking for the mixing from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin

class MyModelAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

http://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#in-django-s-admin-make-the-list-view-sortable

Comment: For some reason, it does not work. Is it because I'm using grappelli? Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance